# shiny plot doesn't show up

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make my first shiny app, in which a number of values are taken in, a number of calculations are performed (which depend on both values in the input and those in the server function), and then the outputs plotted. However, I can either no plot at all in the output (as in the sample below), or can just get the 1:1 line and not my data to show up. I'm not entirely sure where to begin troubleshooting, but I think I have problems with both making the calculations and feeding them into the plot function here. If you have any pointers it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a simplified version of my app:

```
library(shiny)
require(ggplot2)

ui<-fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      titlePanel("mytitle"),
      sliderInput(inputId= "min", label="minratio", value=0, min=0, max=0.499),
      sliderInput(inputId= "max", label="maxratio", value=1, min=0.5, max=1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("valoutput"),
      plotOutput("distPlot",width="100%"))
  )
)

server<-function(input, output){
  BS = function(x) {
    mini=x[1]; maxi=x[2]
    ratio <-seq(from=mini,to=maxi, by=0.01) 
    total<-30*ratio+3
    res = c(ratio,total)
  }
  data<-reactive({as.data.frame("mini"=as.numeric(input$min), "maxi"=as.numeric(input$max))})

  output$valoutput <- renderText({BS(data())[1]})
  output$distplot <- renderPlot({
    d1=BS(data())[1]
    d2=BS(data())[2]
       ggplot()+geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope=1, colour="grey50")+geom_point(aes(x=d1, y=d2))
  }, height = 350, width = 600)

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: `}, height = 350, width = 600) ` why is there a `}` here

Comment: Thats the closing bracket of `renderPlot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BS function is not correct. Change it with this one (with `as.numeric`). Otherwise x[1]/x[2] will be data.frames and will throw an error in `seq()`. Alternatively you could also use double brackets, like `x[[1]]`.

```
  BS = function(x) {
    mini=x[1]; maxi=x[2]
    ratio <-seq(from=as.numeric(mini),to=as.numeric(maxi), by=0.01) 
    total<-30*ratio+3
    res = c(ratio,total)
  }
```

and in your ui your plot output name is not correct. It should be `distplot` not `distPlot`.

And you dont need to call `as.data.frame`, just `data.frame` does the right job, as you want to create a data.frame and not convert an object.

```
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame("mini"=as.numeric(input$min), 
               "maxi"=as.numeric(input$max))
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This fixed the problem. It gave me just one point on my plot where I was expecting 100 (one for each value between mini and maxi), but I fixed that by creating a loop to generate new data from the BS() function inside the plot command.

Comment: I dont think you need a for loop for that, but I dont know exactly what you're trying to plot.

Comment: Thanks - yes a for loop does seem unnecessary and definitely very slow. I'm trying to plot ratio vs. total, which should have 100 x-y pairs for plotting. However, only a single point appears in the plot using the code I put here.