# Why does my plotly donut plot not show up in R Shiny?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to build a donut plot in my shiny app that uses plotly, similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530842/open-pie-chart-donut-chart-in-r-using-plotly-with-count-and-percentage/56531266#56531266) from another question). However' my plot never appears. I've researched other answer (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369658/shiny-plot-doesnt-show-up), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606286/plotly-plot-doesnt-show-up), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834016/plotting-donut-chart-with-plotly)), but they don't get me closer to my answer.

What am I doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

my_colors <- c("#00A3AD", "#FF8200", "#753BBD")

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
        ),
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                plotlyOutput("count_by_person")

            ))
    ))
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    output$count_by_person <- renderPlotly({
        
        data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"),
                       n = c(1, 3, 6),
                       prop = c(.1, .3, .6))

        plot_ly(data, aes(x = 2, y = prop, fill = name)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
            coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
            geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = paste0("n = ", n, ", \n", prop, "%")), color = "white")+
            scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) +
            theme_void() +
            xlim(.5, 2.5)
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try with `ggplot(...)` instead of `plot_ly` and convert your plot afterwards to a plotly object using `plotly::ggplotly`. Unfortunately I'm afraid ggplotly fails to convert your ggplot donut to a plotly donut.

Answer (score 0):

Always try and reproduce the image outside of shiny before bringing it into your application

```
data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"),
                       n = c(1, 3, 6),
                       prop = c(.1, .3, .6))

plot_ly(data, aes(x = 2, y = prop, fill = name)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
            coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
            geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = paste0("n = ", n, ", \n", prop, "%")), color = "white")+
            scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) +
            theme_void() +
            xlim(.5, 2.5)
```

If you run the code in your script, you'll see it returns null because you're trying to use plotly with ggplot syntax

Try starting with the code below to generate a basic donut chart and reading the plotly documentation [here](https://plotly.com/r/pie-charts/) to modify it:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

my_colors <- c("#00A3AD", "#FF8200", "#753BBD")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        plotlyOutput("count_by_person")
        
      ))
  ))
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$count_by_person <- renderPlotly({
    
    data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"),
                   n = c(1, 3, 6),
                   prop = c(.1, .3, .6))
    
    data %>% 
      plot_ly(values=~prop) %>%
      add_pie(hole = 0.6)

  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```